# Julia: serialize error when sending large objects to workers

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I am trying to send data from the master process to worker processes.  I am able to do so just fine with relatively small pieces of data.  But, as soon as they get above a certain size, I encounter a serialize error.

Is there a way to resolve this, or would I just need to break my objects down into smaller pieces and then reassemble them on the workers?  If so, is there a good way to determine ahead of time the max size that I can send (which I suppose may be dependent upon system variables)?  Below is code showing a transfer that works and one that fails.  It's possible the sizes might need to be tinkered with to reproduce on other systems.

```
function sendto(p::Int; args...)
    for (nm, val) in args
        @spawnat(p, eval(Main, Expr(:(=), nm, val)))
    end
end

X1 = rand(10^5, 10^3);
X2 = rand(10^6, 10^3);

sendto(2, X1 = X1) ## works fine

sendto(2, X2 = X2)
ERROR: write: invalid argument (EINVAL)
 in yieldto at /Applications/Julia-0.4.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib
 in wait at /Applications/Julia-0.4.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib
 in stream_wait at /Applications/Julia-0.4.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib
 in uv_write at stream.jl:962
 in buffer_or_write at stream.jl:982
 in write at stream.jl:1011
 in serialize_array_data at serialize.jl:164
 in serialize at serialize.jl:181
 in serialize at serialize.jl:127
 in serialize at serialize.jl:310
 in serialize_any at serialize.jl:422
 in send_msg_ at multi.jl:222
 in remotecall at multi.jl:726
 in sendto at none:3
```

Note: I have plenty of system memory, even for two copies of the larger object, so the problem isn't in that.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be resolved now with Julia 0.5.